# Line numbering on Wordpress frontend

Tags: visual-editor

I've looked at all plugins possible and none have what I need, which is line numbering on front-end only.

Let's say my WordPress post looks like this in the back-end editor:

> My first line
>
> Second line
>
> This is the third

I want my front-end page to look like this

> 01 My first line
>
> 02 Second line
>
> 03 This is the third

Can it be done with code or a plugin?

Comment: Could you be more specific? In what context do you want the line numbers? The whole post? Just a specific "code" block in some posts? Every post?

Comment: I have a custom field created with Advanced Custom Fields plugin. I have set it as WYSIWYG editor. I want line numbering for all the lines in that particular custom field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a WordPress related question, but it's kind of related to visual editor.

If your content is just raw text separated by `<br>` tags, I can't think of any way to do it. But if your content's structure is like this:

```
<p>My first line</p>
<p>Second line</p>
<p>This is the third</p>
```

Then you can use a CSS feature called counter:

```
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}

p::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Line number " counter(section) ": ";
}
```

This will output the following result:

> Line number 1: My first line
>
> Line number 2: Second line
>
> Line number 3: This is the third

Which you can customize it to get your favorite style. It doesn't have to be `p` element, it can be anything. Actually `p` elements are already considered as blocks, and automatically occupy a new line. You can see more examples at [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp).

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I had the text separated by <br> tags, but I adapted it to paragraphs and it's great. Small optional extra question: is there any way to make the first 1 to 9 numbers as 01, 02... 09 ?

Comment: Found it myself just now, thanks again!

p:nth-child(-n+9)::before {    content: "0" counter(section) " ";  }

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry for the delayed comment :)